# Swift: Index out of bounds error, I'm so confused

Tags: swift, indexoutofboundsexception

I can't understand why this "Index out of bounds" error is occuring.
I want to know what's the difference between "Index out of bounds" and "Index out of range" and why my code is causing error. Thank you.

Code

```
var input = readLine()!.split(separator: " ").map{Int($0)!}
var arr = input[1...20]

for (i, a) in arr.enumerated() {
    print(i, a)
}
print(arr[0]) // Index out of bounds
```

Input

```
1 900 901 902 903 904 905 906 907 908 909 910 911 912 913 914 915 916 917 918 919
```

Output

```
0 900
1 901
2 902
3 903
4 904
5 905
6 906
7 907
8 908
9 909
10 910
11 911
12 912
13 913
14 914
15 915
16 916
17 917
18 918
19 919
Swift/SliceBuffer.swift:287: Fatal error: Index out of bounds
2023-05-04 15:01:32.280783+0900 SwiftAlgorithm[86091:6733992] Swift/SliceBuffer.swift:287: Fatal error: Index out of bounds
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s because the array slice isn’t copying the elements and creating a new array, but it creates a “pointer” to the initial one instead, so the indices don’t apply here the same way they would for a new array. This is implemented this way for the benefit of memory efficiency. This is really well described in the [Apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice), as well as how the indices are being kept from the initial array.

Comment: It's not *just* efficiency... if I say I want a slice with indices 17...23, it's nice to be able to continue to work with those indices and not have to translate them to 0...6 after creating the slice.

Comment: The first part of this explanation is irrelevant. The important point is the fact that the indices are maintained i.e. the slice has indexes in the range `1...20` in the question.

Comment: The view metaphor is also misleading since copy on write semantics apply. Modifying the underlying array doesn't change the slice and modifying the slice doesn't change the underlying array.